# HTTP2のフロー制御について次の理解で正しいか教えてください

Tags: http, http2, tcp

コメントを受けてInitialWindowSizeの初期値を修正しました。

### 例1

●InitialWindowSize10K(厳密には65535)でスタート

ストリーム1残り　10K
　コネクション全体残り　64K

●ストリームID1で10K受信

ストリーム1残り　0K
　コネクション全体残り　54K

●WINDOW_UPDATEでストリームID1のWindowSize20K回復

ストリーム1残り　20K
　コネクション全体残り　54K

●ストリームID1で20K受信

ストリーム1残り　0K
　コネクション全体残り　34K

### 例2

●InitialWindowSize10kでスタート

ストリーム1残り　10K
　コネクション全体残り　64K

●ストリームID1で10K受信

ストリーム1残り　0K
　コネクション全体残り　54K

●WINDOW_UPDATEでストリームID0(コネクション全体)のWindowSize20K回復

ストリーム1残り　20K　　(こちらも同時に回復する?)
　コネクション全体残り　74K　(初期値から10K増える?)

Comment: HTTP/2仕様におけるコネクションのウインドウサイズの初期値は65535であり, 64K=65536ではないのでご注意ください.

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。
単純化のために64Kと書いてしまいました。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

例1は正しいです。例2の最後はコネクション全体のみが増えて、ストリーム1は増えません。
正しくは以下のようになります。

ストリーム1残り　0K
コネクション全体残り　74K

Comment: ありがとうございます。
例2のケースですが、その場合はストリームID1を指定したWINDOW_UPDATEを新たに送ってサイズを回復させなければならないのでしょうか？

Comment: はい、ストリーム1のウインドウを増やすための WINDOW_UPDATE が必要です。

Comment: ありがとうございます。助かりました。